# Linear independence question variables

Tags: linear-algebra

are $x^3 - x^2, x - x^2$, $1$ linearly independent and if not is there something similar to it that is? I think they are but I`m not exactly sure what to do

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $a(x^3-x^2)+b(x-x^2)+c\cdot1=0.$ Expand, and gather like powers of $x.$ Since $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is a linearly independent set, what can you then conclude?

Comment: Oh I see now they are linearly independent because they take that form when rearranged

Comment: Take *what* form?

Comment: a(x^3)-(a+b)(x^2) 0(x)+c=0   then since that set is linearly independent a=-a-b=c=0

Comment: Right. And since $a=0$ and $-a-b=0,$ then $b=0.$

Comment: thanks, but if the terms were x^3-x^2, x^3-^2, 1  couldn`t you do the same thing but showing a = b = c =0 but isn't x^3-^2 a linear combination of x^3-x^2  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "x^3-^2"?

Comment: sorry i meant x^3 - x^2 is one times x^3 - x^2

Comment: Well, the set $\{x^3-x^2,x^3-x^2,1\}=\{x^3-x^2,1\},$ so we're still talking about a linearly independent set of vectors. I see what you mean, though. We can start the same way: $$a(x^3-x^2)+b(x^3-x^2)+c\cdot 1=0\\(a+b)x^3+(-a-b)x^2+c\cdot1=0.$$ By linear independence of $\{1,x^2,x^3\},$ we can conclude that $a+b=0,$ $-a-b=0$, and $c=0.$ However, from this, we cannot conclude that $a=b=c=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \in \mathbb{F} $ such that

$$ \lambda_1 (x^3 - x^2) + \lambda_2 (x - x^2) + \lambda_3 \times1 = \Theta $$

Rearranging, we obtain

$$ \lambda_3 x^3 + (- \lambda_1 - \lambda_2)x^2 + \lambda_2x + 1\lambda_3 = \Theta$$

Since the list $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ is  bases in the space of polynomials, then we must have

$ \lambda_3 = 0$, $- \lambda_1 - \lambda_2 = 0 $, $\lambda_2 = 0 $, $\lambda_3 = 0$

Hence, it is obvious that $ \lambda_i = 0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. In other words, your list of vectors is linearly independent by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Are the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ linear independent? (Obviously.)